# Date conversion: error with time

Tags: java, date-format

I got a date from server in the form `E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z` where timezone is `+0200`

I parse it in my own format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` using

```
myFormat.format(serverFormat.parse(dateString));
```

and I get time wrong: it's one hour before. So, if I get `10:00` in conversion I get `09:00`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the problem here is DST - Daylight saving time. The standard is winter time. It  is a summer now, so you get 1 hour difference.
You are using timezone shift syntax `+0200` that does not and cannot support daylight saving because it depends on country.

You should use locale specific syntax of time zone definition, e.g. `Europe/Amsterdam` instead of `+0100`. In addition take a look on API of class `TimeZone`:

- `inDaylightTime(Date date)`
- `useDaylightTime()`

Comment: Problem is that I'm making an rss reader, so I can't do anything about timezone format as it's in the feed. What about if I just add the missing hours in my code? I get 10:00, I add 1, and I got correct date: 11:00

Comment: You can do it but you should be careful. How can you know to add or not to add? If you probably know at least some tip about the locale of  source of the rss feed you can try to distinguish whether it is in DST or not. Otherwise you can do some assumptions. For example say that DST is from Apr, 1 till Oct, 1. This will be OK for most countries most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the timezone of the returned value which most probably is the cause of the issue.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");    
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2")); 

System.out.println( formatter.format(serverFormat.parse(dateString));
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
```